# How to set UI and Email to recipient spoken language

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having trouble making this work.  I have an embedded signing view for my users as well as email notifications that are sent to the user as the flow progresses, such as perhaps reminders or CC's when signing is complete.

From what I understand the UI and the email are controlled separately

1. The UI is supposed to pick up on the browser settings and display accordingly
2. The email I can set in the emailNotification setting in the Recipient through the API for each recipient

I haven't gotten around to number 2 yet, but please confirm.  As for the first, I have changed my browser (Google Chrome) to be in Spanish through their Settings/language and Input settings.  Relaunched Chrom and it is in Spanish. For instance the Settings page is all in Spanish.  But when I click on the signing link on my page and it takes me to the embedded signing view, it still is in English.

How can I ensure the UI will be in Spanish for my Spanish customers?  I don't want them to have to set it themselves via the hard-to-find language control at the bottom of the page.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Nevermind.  Setting the emailNotification/supportedLanguage on the Recipient changes both the language presented in the embedded signing view as well as any email notifications that recipient gets.  This despite contrary information I have seen in these forums and is the only way I got it to work.  The embedded view DID NOT pick up the language set in the browser as is alleged throughout this forum as well as in DocuSign support documents.

Comment: Thanks Joe, any way you can answer your own question for the benefit of the community?  I'll up-vote if you post an answer...  Thx

Comment: I already did.  Everything past the "nevermind" is the answer.  :)

Comment: Right but that's just a comment on the question you posted, not an official answer.  You actually have the ability to answer your own question, that way when people see the question listed in search results they see it has been answered.  If it's just a comment then it looks like it has not been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the emailNotification/supportedLanguage on the Recipient changes both the language presented in the embedded signing view as well as any email notifications that recipient gets. This despite contrary information I have seen in these forums and is the only way I got it to work. The embedded view DID NOT pick up the language set in the browser as is alleged throughout this forum as well as in DocuSign support documents